# While Loops Problem with Python Twitter Crawler

Tags: python, html, twitter, while-loop, web-crawler

I'm continuing writing my twitter crawler and am running into more problems. Take a look at the code below:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = 'http://mobile.twitter.com/NYTimesKrugman'

def gettweets(soup):
    tags = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : "list-tweet"})#to obtain tweet of a follower
    for tag in tags: 
        print tag.renderContents()
        print ('\n\n')

def are_more_tweets(soup):#to check whether there is more than one page on mobile 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id: 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        test_b = str(b)
        if test_b.find('more'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def getnewlink(soup): #to get the link to go to the next page of tweets on twitter 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d

def checkforstamp(soup): # the parser scans a webpage to check if any of the tweets are   
    times = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {'class': 'status_link'})
    for time in times:
        stamp = time.renderContents()
        test_stamp = str(stamp)
        if test_stamp.find('month'): 
            return True
        else:
            return False


response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
gettweets(soup)
stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
print 'stamp' + str(stamp)
print 'tweets' +str (tweets)
while (not stamp) and tweets: 
    b = getnewlink(soup)
    print b
    red = urllib2.urlopen(b)
    html = red.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    gettweets(soup)
    stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
    tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
print 'done'
```

The code works in the following way: 
For a single user NYTimesKrugman 
-I obtain all tweets on a single page(gettweets)
-provided more tweets exist(are more tweets) and that I haven't obtained a month of tweets yet(checkforstamp), I get the link for the next page of tweets
-I go to the next page of tweets (entering the while loop) and continue the process until one of the above conditions is violated

However, I have done extensive testing and determined that I am not actually able to enter the while loop. Rather, the program is not doing so. This is strange, because my code is written such that tweets are true and stamp should yield false. However, I'm getting the below results:  I am truly baffled!

```
<div>
<span>
<strong><a href="http://mobile.twitter.com/nytimeskrugman">NYTimeskrugman</a></strong>
<span class="status">What Would I Have Done? <a rel="nofollow"   href="http://nyti.ms/nHxb8L" target="_blank" class="twitter_external_link">http://nyti.ms/nHxb8L</a></span>
</span>
<div class="list-tweet-status">
<a href="/nytimeskrugman/status/98046724089716739" class="status_link">3 days ago</a>
</div>
<div class="list-tweet-actions">
</div>
</div>




stampTrue
tweetsTrue
done
>>>
```

If someone could help that'd be great. Why can I not get more than 1 page of tweets? Is my parsing in checkstamp being done incorrectly? Thanx.

Comment: Can you post what prints out from your code? Specifically, stamp and tweets.

Comment: Hey. I will do so, with the fix that I specified below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if test_stamp.find('month'):
```

will evaluate to `True` if it doesn't find `month`, because it returns `-1` when it doesn't find the substring. It would only evaluate to `False` here if `month` was at the beginning of the string, so its position was `0`.

You need

```
if test_stamp.find('month') != -1:
```

or just

```
return test_stamp.find('month') != -1
```

Comment: Hey agf! Thanks for the suggestion. On the positive side, the crawler now keeps going through page after page of twitter tweets. On the negative side, it doesn't ever stop...Would you have any suggestions as to how I can modify my code so as to make sure that the crawler stops looking for tweets at the 3 month mark? I originally tried to look for the tag that indicated a time stamp and stop it when the soup read 3 months but that doesn't seem to be working at all...I would want this method to work for any twitter user, however, given that my code is a small snippet of a larger program. Thanks

Comment: Since I've answered your question, please accept my answer. You need to `print time_stamp`; if it never says `x month(s) ago`, then you need to fix your `findall` or something. Comment here again with the results if you need more help so it notifies me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkforstamp` function returns non-empty, defined strings:

```
return 'True'
```

So `(not stamp)` will always be false.

Change it to return booleans like `are_more_tweets` does:

```
return True
```

and it should be fine.

For reference, see the [boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) documentation:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). **All other values are interpreted as true.**
>
> ...
>
> The operator **not** yields True if its argument is false, False otherwise.

Edit:

Same problem with the `if` test in `checkforstamp`. Since `find('substr')` returns `-1` when the substring is not found, `str.find('substr')` in boolean context will be `True` if there is no match according to the rules above.

That is not the only place in your code where this problem appears. Please review all your tests.

Comment: Hey. I believe that was a typo. I changed it as you suggested but I am experiencing the same problem as before. The crawler will not go beyond 1 page. Help! Thanx!

Comment: I've attached the end of the output of code - Basically the crawler pulls all the tweets off a page. I omitted those but included only those in the end of a page. Plus the stuff that I wanted printed out.

Comment: You've missed that it was __printing__ as `True` so that couldn't be the problem -- it was actually ending up in that branch of the `if` statement. See my answer.